# How to do lazy loading image on UICollectionview cell using Alamofire 4.?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage

I have downloaded Alamofire 4 using cocoa pod. Web api is working fine, but for showing image on collection view cell using a URL, I am not getting method for lazy loading. Kindly help me how can I do this?

**Pod file format:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'XXX' do

  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

  use_frameworks!

pod 'Alamofire', '~> 4.0'

  # Pods for XXX

  target 'XXX' do

    inherit! :search_paths

    # Pods for testing

  end

  target 'XXX' do

    inherit! :search_paths

    # Pods for testing
  end

end
```

[image]

Comment: Alamofire lazy loading of images is probably best done with [AlamofireImage](https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage).

Comment: @Rob AlamofireImage is not downloaded with Alamofire 4 and when I downloaded AlamofireImage 3.1 with Alamofire 4. it is showing error.

Comment: Yes, it's separate. What error did you get? What did your Podfile look like for that?

Comment: I used this-  
Alamofire.request(.GET, strImgURL).response { (request, response, data, error) in
            cell.imgCell.image = UIImage(data: data, scale:1)
        }
And error extra argument in call

Comment: I have added a screenshot of pod file with my Questions @rob kindly check it.

Comment: First, re alamofireimage, I was suggesting using UIImageView extension. It's the easiest way to do lazy loading of images. Second, `response` now takes single parameter.

Comment: See [Response Handler](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#response-handler).

Comment: @Rob, I want to know that how can I use common viewcontroller on rear & front both using swrevealviewcontroller.